# Why is this minimization with Boole functions failing?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am running this command in Mathematica 8.0.4.0:

```
Minimize[(x1*1 - 1)^2 + (x1*0.823202 + x2*1 - 0.7551)^2 + 
         lambda*(Boole[x1 != 0] + Boole[x2 != 0]), {x1, x2}]
```

Now, with `lambda=0` (negating the `Boole` functions), I get:

```
{7.70372*10^-34, {x1 -> 1., x2 -> -0.068102}}
```

With `lambda=1`, I get:

```
{2., {x1 -> 1., x2 -> -0.068102}}
```

It seems to be ignoring the Boole functions, because clearly `x2 -> 0` is a better solution:

```
(x1*1 - 1)^2 + (x1*0.823202 + x2*1 - 0.7551)^2 + 
 lambda*(Boole[x1 != 0] + Boole[x2 != 0]) /. {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 0}

1.00464
```

I assume Mathematica is minimizing this function numerically; is it simply incapable of doing this with `Boole` functions, given their stepwise nature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It switches to `NMinimize` (a numerical solver) automatically because you have inexact numbers in the expression, which [don't go well with symbolic calculations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2496/12).

Use `Rationalize` to convert them to exact numbers.

```
labmda = 1

Minimize[Rationalize[(x1*1 - 1)^2 + (x1*0.823202 + x2*1 - 0.7551)^2 + 
   lambda*(Boole[x1 != 0] + Boole[x2 != 0])], {x1, x2}]

{420574853802/419415383201, {x1 -> 405399957550/419415383201, x2 -> 0}}
```

Actually I am surprised that `Minimize` can handle things as general as `Boole`.

Comment: So with the addition of Rationalize, it actually solves it analytically? How is that possible with the Boole functions?

Comment: The problem I am really trying to solve is a little more complex, and the Rationalize trick doesn't seem to work for that: Minimize[Rationalize[(x1*1 - 1)^2 + (x1*0.823202 + x2*1 - 0.7551)^2 + (x1*0.396947 + x2*0.823202 + x3*1 - 0.3738)^2 + lambda*(Boole[x1 != 0] + Boole[x2 != 0] + Boole[x3 != 0])], {x1, 
  x2, x3}]

Comment: Use `Minimize[Rationalize[(x1*1 - 1)^2 + (x1*0.823202 + x2*1 - 
      0.7551)^2 + (x1*0.396947 + x2*0.823202 + x3*1 - 0.3738)^2 + 
   lambda*(Boole[x1 != 0] + Boole[x2 != 0] + Boole[x3 != 0]), 0], {x1,
   x2, x3}]` to force Rationalize to produce an exact fraction even if the denominator will be terribly large.  Sorry for no time for a more detailed explanation ...

Comment: That works, thanks! A more detailed explanation of what is going on would be nice when you have time.

Comment: @Szabolcs @Craig Just wanted to add that `SetPrecision[..., Infinity]` is a possible alternative to `Rationalize[..., 0]`, which most likely will give a better representation if the inexact numbers are intended to represent particular machine double values rather than just some arbitrary real number.